# UILabel to animate left and back again from right

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, xcode7

So what I want to achieve is to have a UILabel text which should animate like the LED billboards that present news and various other texts outside malls etc. The UILabel should not change position, but the text in it should move from its current position towards the left bound of the UILabel and comes back again from the right side, kinda like a queue. Sample texts are:

**Before Animation:**

"I would like to implement this..."

**During Animation:**

"like to implement this... I would "

"ment this... I would like to imple"
etc

And this should go on for as long as I want the animation to remain, probably forever.

Please any help would do wonders. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pod MarqueeLabel
```

[MarqueeLabel](http://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel) provide this feature. Just set the class name of your label to MarqueeLabel as below:-

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblLocation: MarqueeLabel!
```

Set the properties according to your requirement:-

1. Duration
2. FadeLength
3. MarqueeType

Answer (score -1):

here is a simple solution:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.label.text = @"I would like to implement this...";
    self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.3f target:self
                                       selector:@selector(animateText)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)animateText{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[self.label.text substringFromIndex:1]];
    [str appendString:[self.label.text substringToIndex:1]];
    self.label.text = str;
}
```

Comment: Please something in Swift.. ObjectiveC's selectors are way easy; and pfft, swift's are a horror story :P